# Powershell Start-Process / msiexec is not working for me

Tags: powershell

When I try to run the script nothing happens, software is not installed. Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

```
# Software path
$SevenZip   = $PSScriptRoot + "\MSI\7z2201-x64.msi"


Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList " /i $SevenZip /quiet /qn /norestart ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

I tried

```
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList " /i $SevenZip /quiet /L*v 'C:\Info.log'" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

But no file was found to read the error. Also I received this dialog box:

[image]

Comment: It says `/quite` instead of `/quiet` in one of the snippets

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it, same result but the dialog box is gone

Comment: In your first example there's a random single quote as well.

Comment: Yeah sorry that was when I edited the question. It's not there on the actual script.

Comment: Use `-ArgumentList "/i $SevenZip /quiet /L*v \`"C:\Info.log\`""`. Always use double quotation marks within a command-line you pass to `Start-Process`.

Comment: I just did but still no file found in C: drive even when I enabled hidden files.

Comment: Do you run PowerShell as administrator?

Comment: I just did, and the file showed up and the software was installed finally. Thanks!